# How can I apply the ':hover' element styles to the '::after' element?

Tags: html, css

I have created a Ribbon background, using CSS, where I have stacked a social media icon on top.  The ribbon is made up of 2 parts.  The top half being a square and the bottom half being where the 'frilly bit' resides.  The code is as follows:

```
#facebook-icon{ 
    background-color: #7d4826;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 23px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#facebook-icon::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
    border-left: 17px solid #7d4826;
    border-right: 18px solid #7d4826;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

I want the ribbon to change colour, when a user scrolls over the image.  To do this, I have inserted the following code:

```
#facebook-icon:hover{
    color: #7d4826;
    background-color: lavender;
}
```

This only affects the top half of the ribbon.  To provide the same effect to the bottom half, I applied the following code:

```
#facebook-icon::after:hover{
    color: #7d4826;
    background-color: lavender;
}
```

Unfortunately, this did not seem to work.  Is anyone aware of any workarounds?

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mcve] in the question itself. For CSS questions, this should include the HTML to which it applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just swap them around, So when user hover on the element with #facebook-icon you want the ::after part to also change. If you create a plunker I can apply the changes there for you and it would be also to see the HTML :)

```
#facebook-icon:hover::after{
    color: #7d4826;
    background-color: lavender;
}
```